# Can we make a cctexture from a sprite which dont have data in resource folder in cocos2dx c++ in ios

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I made a sprite

```
CCSprite *sprite=CCSprite::create("1.png");
```

1.png and `mask_circle.png` is in my resource folder

```
CCSprite* mask = CCSprite::create("mask_circle.png");
mask->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width*.20, winSize.height*.80));
sprite->setPosition(ccp(mask->getContentSize().width/2,mask->getContentSize().height/2));
```

Now I masked this image by using `CCMask.CCmask` inherits `CCSprite`

```
CCMask* masked = CCMask::create(mask , sprite);
masked->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width*.20, winSize.height*.80));
this->addChild(masked,2);
```

Now this **masked** pointer of class CCMask is created using the 2 sprites which have 1.png and mask_circle.png in resources folder
Can we create a texture of masked object or not?It doesn't have any resource.It is created by code using other 2 sprites.
I want to create texture of this masked object.
If not possible is there a way to save this masked object sprite to my resource folder by some name like myimage.png?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get a texture this way directly, but a way around it is to use [RenderTexture](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0rc2/d9/ddc/classcocos2d_1_1_render_texture.html). Draw the sprites by calling `visit` on them in a `begin`/`end` block and then use the appropriate method for saving the result to a file. After that you can load the image as a texture.